# How can I use Chart.JS for minute-by-minute data?

Tags: jquery, json, logging, graph, chart.js

I am trying to use Chart.JS to visualize temperature and humidity patterns throughout the day for an automated garden. For each day I have a JSON file which has a temperature and humidity reading logged every minute by a Raspberry Pi. I've been able to pull this data in and graph it fine, but I can't seem to find a way to reduce the number of ticks and labels on the x-axis, nor to format them as anything but the source data, for which I'm using a millisecond epoch. If I give my own list of labels (i.e. 00:00, 01:00, 02:00, etc) then it only shows me a few data points, and they do not correspond to the actual readings at those times. I have tried many different options for how to format the xAxes array to no avail. Please find my code below, and bare in mind that I have not worked much with Chart.JS in the past. It seems like it wants to create a tick/label for every data point. Can this be changed? I want to get the x-axis to show the hours of the day instead. I appreciate any help that somebody with more experience may be able to provide.

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost/overlay/data/052722.json?_=' + new Date().getTime(), function(data) {
        // Extract the datetime and temperature values from the data
        var datetime = data.map(function(d) {
            return Date.parse(d.time);
        });
        var temperature = data.map(function(d) {
            return d.temperature;
        });
        var humidity = data.map(function(d) {
            return d.humidity;
        });
        var labels = ["00:00", "06:00", "12:00", "18:00"];
        
        // Create a new Chart.js line chart
        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: datetime,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Temperature',
                    data: temperature,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    borderWidth: 1
                },
                {
                    label: 'Humidity',
                    data: humidity,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(99, 255, 255, 0.2)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(99, 255, 255, 1)',
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        type: 'time',
                        time: {
                            unit: 'hour'
                            
                        }, ticks: {
                            source: 'auto'
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

And my JSON file is structured as follows:

```
[
   {
    "temperature": 13.5,
    "humidity": 76.7,
    "time": "2022-05-27 00:00:00"
  },
   {
    "temperature": 13.5,
    "humidity": 76.9,
    "time": "2022-05-27 00:01:00"
  },
   {
    "temperature": 13.5,
    "humidity": 77.0,
    "time": "2022-05-27 00:02:00"
  },
   {
    "temperature": 13.4,
    "humidity": 76.2,
    "time": "2022-05-27 00:03:00"
  },
...
   {
    "temperature": 19.0,
    "humidity": 90.3,
    "time": "2022-05-27 23:57:00"
  },
   {
    "temperature": 19.0,
    "humidity": 90.3,
    "time": "2022-05-27 23:58:00"
  },
   {
    "temperature": 19.0,
    "humidity": 90.2,
    "time": "2022-05-27 23:59:00"
  }
]
```

I appreciate any help you may be able to provide!

Also, note that I can easily alter the code for saving this data and change the format it's saved in. I just currently do not have the Pi collecting any data and am using an older data log.

I have tried re-formatting the code, using different data logs, specifying tick options, such as "count", "source", using my own array of labels, getting help from ChatGPT, changing the format of the data logs, I've tried a lot. I don't know if this is even functionality that exists.

Comment: It would be easier to debug within sample data array or code posted on online editor. As for now you could check autoSkip and maxTicksLimit property to reduce an amount of ticks. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/?h=autoskip Also, if you would like to format data on xAxis, you could declare in xAxes array, ticks object a sample callback: function (value) { return value; }, where you proceed a value modification.

Comment: See, the problem is that those properties seem to have no effect! I updated "xAxes" to the following: 

xAxes: [{
   type: 'time',
   time: {
         unit: 'hour'
                            
   }, ticks: {
         source: 'auto',
         maxTicksLimit: 10,
         autoSkip: true
   }
}],

But the graph looks exactly the same. The same goes for any formatting I try to add or callback functions. I don't know why they aren't working. I feel like I am making a basic error or something. Do I maybe need to have two sets for the xAxes? Still trying more things to make this work

Comment: This is what the graph looks like: https://imgur.com/a/0xeDQ90

Comment: I've figured it out! Instead of defining the options for xAxes and yAxes I had to define them for x and y and remove the arrays. The new code is working. I knew it had to be something simple like this. Thank you for your help!